# No rule to make target '|' neded by

Tags: gnu-make

I'm catching a make error:

```
make: no rule to make `|' needed by cryptest.exe
```

Here's the recipe:

```
cryptest.exe: public_service | libcryptopp.a $(TESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTOBJS) ./libcryptopp.a $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

The ***|*** is an [Order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html). Order-only prerequisites usually work, so I'm not sure what the trouble is in this instance.

Why am I receiving the make error?

---

My apologies for the question. I image this has been asked and answered many times before. Unfortunately, neither Google nor Bing seem to work with characters like ***|***.

Comment: What version of GNU make?

Comment: @200_success - gmake version is 3.79.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order-only prerequisites is a feature introduced in GNU Make 3.80.

Excerpt from the [`NEWS`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?id=3.80) file:

> Version 3.80
>
> - A new feature exists: order-only prerequisites.  These prerequisites   affect the order in which targets are built, but they do not impact the rebuild/no-rebuild decision of their dependents.  That is to say, they allow you to require target B be built before target A, without requiring that target A will always be rebuilt if target B is updated. Patch for this feature provided by Greg McGary `<…@mcgary.org>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `.FEATURES` default variable, which you could use to test for the existence of features, was introduced in GNU Make 3.81 — even later.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought that might be the case. But [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) did not discuss a limitation on the feature, so I made the leap its always available. I'll try to build and install Gmake 4.1 (would should be a treat...)